# Workbook_BeforeClose does not work

Tags: vba, excel

What I understand from this "Workbook_BeforeClose" is that a command should work after when click "X" to close Excel.

My code is;

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Sheets("Makro").Range("A2") = 0   
End Sub
```

When I reopen this excel workbook, I want to see that Range "A2" is zero ("0"). But I reopen the excel, it is not zero. I cannot understand.

I wonder if I misunderstood this vba code.

If you help me about this, I would be appreciate you.

Comment: Do you want to save the file after this last change?

Comment: It doesn't matter other changes in excel file but I might save. I just want to save A2 cell. Thus, when I open the excel file, I need to see A2 cell as zero always.

Comment: _"I just want to save A2 cell"_ - You want to save only one cell w/o saving entire file? :))

Answer (score 2):

Try it as,

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Me.Worksheets("Makro").Range("A2") = 0
    Me.Save
End Sub
```

If you don't want it saved then change it to,

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Me.Worksheets("Makro").Range("A2") = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I cannot it work properly. Second code piece is what I am lookin for. Nevertheless, both of them didn't work. By the way, word of "Me." doesn't look like a key word in my code because it is not blue. I am very new in vba, please excuse me.

Comment: I did test it on an otherwise blank workbook so there may be other factors at play with yours. But as long as you have a resolution I suppose the second will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()
Sheets("Makro").Range("A2") = 0   
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Auto_Close()
Sheets("Makro").Range("A2") = 0   
End Sub
```

codes solved my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2")

```
.Value = "ABC"
```

End With

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Found this question trying to fix my issue, turns out their code was correct.
There's no need for `Option Explicit` or a `Save`

Just make sure you have the

`Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)`

in the `ThisWorkbook` Window. It won't work if it's in one of the sheets or modules.